# BesselJ function with double parameters

Tags: math.net

When I want to use the function BesselJ(double n,double z) the compiler complains with the following message:

> The type 'Complex' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.
> You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Numerics,
> Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

The documentation states that there are two flavors of this function, one for two parameters of type double and the other one for two parameters, one double and one complex, but it seems that the only one available in the library is the latter.

Does any one know how to use the version with two parameters of type double?
Thanks in advance.

SpecialFunctions.BesselJ(delta,x), where delta and x are of type double

Comment: what documentation are you referring to? Can you add the link?